# how to globally store data in a struct for multiple functions

Tags: c++, struct

I have this simple struct defined at the top of my cpp file:

```
struct sServersArray
{
TCHAR sName[128];
};
struct sServersArray sServers[1024] = {0};
```

What I do is store data into the .Name field in one function, and read the data in other  functions.

I know this is taking up valuable memory (off of the stack/heap, I don't know which or why), and I know it should be moved somehow - to a class perhaps?

Can someone show me how to move this struct to a class and be able to have my other functions access it? I am concerned about using too much stack/heap space and know this is the wrong way to go about doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
struct sServersArray
{
  std::string sName;
};

std::vector<sServersArray> sServers;
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 9 seconds. +1, but I'm not removing my answer since it covers different ground.

Comment: Great, thanks for the code formatting. How do I reference it in my own code?

And do I need a class or just keep it at the top of the CPP file?

Answer (score 2):

Global data is allocated in a separate section of memory, not the stack, not the "heap" (free store).

Simple solution: read server names to an `std::vector<std::string>` and pass that around by reference. That way, your data is allocated on the heap, there are no more globals to worry about and you get rid of the arbitrary length restrictions.

(You could also create a global `vector`, but please don't do that. Global data is a code smell.)

Comment: So the "heap" is storage that is dynamically allocated and only limited by the amount of system memory, then?